# Is there a pseudo-hash function that generates words from an input?

Tags: algorithm, hash

I am trying to find, or come up with, an algorithm that performs a hash on an input to generate an output of two or three words.

For example:

- "ABCD" -> "tree blue"
- "WXYZ" -> "curious acorn"

  The algorithm needs to

  1. Always produce the same result for the same input
  2. Have a low probability of collision, but it does not need to be a strict as a "real" hash
  3. Have a moderate difficulty of recreating the input, but it does not need to be as strict as a "real" hash

One thought I have is to use a normal hash function to create a hash value, and then use the first few characters to select words:

- "ABCD" -> "2fd4e1c..." -> {"2fd": "tree", "4e1": "blue"}

But I'm not certain what a good lookup algorithm would be (for making a uniform distribution across all words in my table) and whether this satisfies my requirements above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a collision probability smaller than *2<sup>-k</sup>*, you want to have approximately *2<sup>2k</sup>* bits of entropy due to the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). That gives you a rough estimate on how many words you need in your dictionary for a given number of words or vice versa.

Your suggested approach looks sound: Use a good standard hash function, and then, for a dictionary of size *n*, just use the first *log<sub>2</sub>(n)* bits of the hash for the first word, the next *log<sub>2</sub>(n)* bits for the second etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Looks like I'll definitely need three or more words, unless I'm going to import a huge library. Good call.